# Number of ways to map two sets to each other using Induction

Tags: combinatorics, functions, discrete-mathematics

I want to prove via induction the number of ways that a set of size $n$ can map to another set of size $m$. From [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84162/counting-functions-between-two-sets) question I believe the answer is $m^n$ however I am unsure how to prove this via induction.

I believe I can prove the base case as when $n=1$ then there can only be $m$ different ways that this can be mapped as there is only only $1$ element in the first set.

However I cannot prove the $n=k+1$ case.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This could be the *definition* of $m^n$.

Answer (score 1):

The base case is completed. Now assume the result is true for $n\in\mathbb{N}$. If $X=\{x_1, \dots, x_{n+1}\}$, then let $A\subset X$ be defined as $A=\{x_1, \dots, x_{n}\}$. You know that there are $m^n$ possible functions $f: A\to Y$ (here $|Y|=m$). For each of these functions, let $f_j: X\to Y$ be defined as $f_j(x)=f(x)$ if $x\in A$ and $f(x)=y_j$ if $x\not\in A$. Here $1\leq j\leq m$. This characterizes all possible functions $g: X\to Y$. There are $m^{n+1}$ of them